# Class:hover works on Firefox but doesn't work on Chrome nor IE9

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer-9, rotateanimation

Here the Problem, I want to make this text rotate on mouse hover, this code works perfectly on Firefox but not on Chrome(Version 25.0.1364.97 m) nor IE9

http://jsfiddle.net/B2u4j/1/

```
<div class="holder circulate" > Hello World </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.holder {
border: 10px solid #FFFFFF;
float: left;
margin-left:0px;
margin-top:0px;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #333333;
overflow: hidden;
transition: all 0.5s Ease;
 }

.circulate:hover {

transform: rotate(360deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Firefox */  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add vendor prefixed properties for `transition` for better cross-browser support.

```
.holder {
    border: 10px solid #FFFFFF;
    ...
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
         -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
```

You can keep up-to-date with which properties need to be prefixed for which browsers over at http://css3please.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use `-webkit-transition: all 0.5s Ease;`